# CSS Alternate color to child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to show **alternate** colors to child element inside of my div by following syntax:

```css
    div:nth-of-type(odd).z .b {
      background: red;
      height: 20px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    div:nth-of-type(even).z .b {
      background: blue;
      height: 20px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="z">
  <div class="a"></div>`
</div>
<div class="z">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="z">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="z">
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
<div class="z">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

[Related JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinit069/p1t2jgd8/)

But it is not having alternate colors, the last b class is like an even child though there is only 3 b classes. Please provide the solution.

Comment: @Paulie_D it was only a formatting issue, he actually included code.

Comment: You're looking for `nth-of-class`....which doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking to do - something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p1t2jgd8/2/)? I don't understand the point of the `.a` elements, as they aren't visible.

Comment: The last B class is using the style for odd. I'm not seeing what you're describing. I changed the formatting of your divs a little and gave things labels. Does this help at all? https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/p1t2jgd8/1/

Comment: @RyanLittle I think he is trying to "enumerate" the b elements, while other arbitrary elements may occur in between. This however does not work with those pseudo selectors, as they always require a common parent element.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is answered below, but I can't be sure because the question is still very vague. I'm not sure what is expected at all.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, yes my doubt was answered below. but i thought of doing it through css and not to indulge into javascript, but I think there is no way round other than using js

Comment: @VinitAgarwal check out my answer it involves no JS.

Comment: A picture/sketch would go a really long way to show what OP is expecting for certain! That said, my interpretation of the question with a [pure html+css solution](https://jsfiddle.net/mLs4zyo1/1/)  -- note, I'm presuming OP added `z` and `b` in attempts  to solve the essence of a question they were going for.

Answer (score 3):

The css is exactly working, like you defined it. To understand what happened, I modified [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwLsgy82/).

It takes all divs with the class `z` (your base divs so to speak) and applies the `even` and `odd` selectors. Then it looks for children with classes `b`.

Thus is applies the first rule on two of your divs, and the second (blue) on the `b` div of your second `z` div.

However, what I assume you are trying to do - count the odd/evenness of your `b` elements is not possible with `nth-of-type` or `nth-children` selectors, because these require the elements to have the same parent, which is not the case for your markup. Also your selector then should look like the following:

```
.b:nth-of-type(even)   /*this does not work!*/
```

I think the only solution is using javascript in this case. I used jQuery, but of course it's possible with plain js as well (and most likely there are more efficient selectors, but this was the first, that popped into my mind).

```
$(".b")
   .filter(":even").addClass("even").end()
   .filter(":odd").addClass("odd");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gwLsgy82/1/

Edit for completeness' sake:

I always put the pseudo selectors last, and also avoid unnecessary selector weight, this improves readability as well as performance. This means, I'd write:

```
.z:nth-of-type(odd) .b
```

instead of your selector `div:nth-of-type(odd).z .b`

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually I don't wanted to use js, So I passed a empty div after class a

Comment: I am pretty certain, that there exists no *css only* solution for your markup situation. Having two classes for the even and odd elements and then applying these classes via javascript is probably the closest without altering your html.

Comment: OP: *Thanks for reply, actually I don't wanted to use js, So I passed a empty div after class a* So your answer wasn't helpful OP *altered the HTML* I answered to the letter of the question. I'm entitled to my opinion that section is a div. If you read my answer, I also said that there is a sacrifice of semantics.

Comment: I'm totally fine with you being entitled to your opinion, even if it is obviously wrong. I just wanted to be so kind to inform of your misconception, what you are doing with this is entirely up to you. I just don't get it what is up with your hostility in all of your comments...

Comment: @VinitAgarwal where you able to solve the problem? At the moment, I can't seem to see how passing an empty div like you stated in your first comment is going to solve the problem. Do you need any additional help?

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the help, No I have found the solution by passing a empty div through for loop and giving the same class name.

Comment: @VinitAgarwal That's sounds great. Feel free to share your finding as an answer. You then can either accept your own answer as best solution or you could accept Zer00ne's or my answer, if you found them helpful. By accepting an answer you mark your question as solved to the SO community, mark the most helpful answer (which very well can be yours) and reward the Author of the answer as well.